# Is anyone working on getting the styled components CSS prop working with esbuild "natively"?

Tags: styled-components, esbuild

I was tempted to try building a few of our applications with esbuild and it is SO MUCH FASTER ...like 300ms instead of 30 seconds or more for production.

Everything worked ...except where we'd used the css prop API for styled components.  I guess that was pretty obvious since the css prop API is only enabled using the Babel plugin for styled components - and I wasn't trying to bring Babel into my esbuild ...build.

Before I even consider heading down the path of writing an esbuild plugin to start manipluating the file contents - has anyone else been here?  Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.